# How to use a UIScrollview with a few images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have not used a UIScrollView before, and I just wanted to know how I could use paging in a UIScrollView, where there would be a different image on each page, and depending on the page currently selected I would set the image on that page to a separate UIImageView's image.

So if anyone could tell me how to do this that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Snipplr reference [here](http://snipplr.com/view/29068/images-in-a-scroll-view/) gives you a great barebones look into how to set this up.

Comment: What? No, you don't set I as anything, this will allow you to use an Array of photos to layout the images.
You'll need to specify the width and height of the images though.

Comment: I get the error: UIImage length unrecognized method... from this code:https://gist.github.com/813923

Comment: Have you populated it with your own images?